# IE flash background problems (swfobject)

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, swfobject

I've slowly been adapting this site to work on browsers and I just need some help getting it working in ie.

I have a full page flash background that apparently does not show in IE - [polivision.tv/test.html](http://polivision.tv/test.html)

Using swfobject, the html for the code is

```
<object id="background_vid" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="movie" value="background-vid.swf" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#000" />   
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="background-vid.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="loop" value="true" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#000" /> 
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" title="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a><br />
    You need <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">Flash Player 8</a> and allow javascript to see the content of this site..
  </div>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Thanks,
Shoma

Answer (score 0):

you have the wrong syntax for conditional comments.. it should be..

`<!--[if !IE]>-->`

`<![endif]-->`

Not sure if that solves your problem though. Let me know if that doesn't do it.

Also, you dont need the `clsid`  anymore, you can just use `type` for both IE and Fx. You should specify the `movie` parameter regardless.

How does `swfobject` play a role in this? You're not using any js?

Comment: I was under the impression that that was how the comments were supposed to look with swfobject - http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Comment: unfortunately does not work.  And I've confirmed that the comments are indeed supposed to look like that.

Answer (score 0):

there's a working example of a full-browser SWF at http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/100-width-and-height-in-browser/

it has been successfully tested in IE, Firefox (Mac & Windows), Safari (Mac & Windows), and Opera (Mac & Windows). i suggest copying the source code and editing it as needed.

notes:

1. you don't need to specify loop=true or quality=high since those are flash player defaults
2. you don't need to specify the movie param for the non-IE object
3. clsid *should* be included for IE to ensure consistency from version to version